# Rewrites: How to differenciate between two similar locations in nginx configuration

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have two similar sites that I am now going to combine into one, so I'm redirecting the links from one to aim at the other using the nginx config in sites-enabled.

Since the 'forwarded from' site uses 'pretty urls', I've just been doing a rule like this:

```
location /about/about-us/ { rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.thenewwebsite.com/aboutus.htm permanent; }
```

But, I have addresses structured like this:

```
/fruit/, /fruit/apples/, /fruit/bananas/, /fruit/12/
```

When I use the same location rewrite formula (resulting in 4 location lines), the general /fruit/ address seems to overrule the more specific addresses (/fruit/bananas/).

How should I have written this?

Comment: The longer prefix takes precedence, but you would need to specify all of it (including the trailing `/`). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for the syntax and processing rules.

Comment: Can you show the actual location definitions, and the order they're in?